# How to sum time from multiple connected tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to find the time duration of an online course by adding the individual lesson lengths together. However, each lesson belongs to a chapter which in turn belongs to a course.

```
Course table
| course_id | name | date | ...

Chapter table
| chapter_id | course_id | name |

Lesson table
| lesson_id | chapter_id | name | length |
```

If the `lesson` table was linked to the `course` table directly, I would just use the following:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `length` ) ) ) AS totaltime 
                    FROM lesson 
                    WHERE course_id = 'WEB001'
```

How can I sum the lengths of all the lessons that belong to a course by going through the `chapter` table?

P.S. 'length' attribute is of type 'time'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make the adequate relations within your data.

Taking things by pieces, let's first select the data you need:

```
SELECT c.*, ch.chapter_id, ch.name, l.lesson_id, l.`length`
FROM course AS c
    INNER JOIN chapter AS ch ON c.course_id = ch.course_id
    INNER JOIN lesson AS l ON ch.chapter_id = l.chapter_id
WHERE c.course_id = 'WEB001'
```

As you can see, you have all the data you need.

Now, your query is rather obvious:

```
SELECT SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( l.`length` ) AS totaltime 
FROM course AS c
    INNER JOIN chapter AS ch ON c.course_id = ch.course_id
    INNER JOIN lesson AS l ON ch.chapter_id = l.chapter_id
WHERE c.course_id = 'WEB001'
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, just had to remove the extra closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT c.*,
       SEC_TO_TIME( (SELECT SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `length` ))
                     FROM lesson l JOIN
                          chapter ch
                          ON l.chapter_id = ch.chapter_id
                     WHERE ch.course_id = c.course_id
                    )
                  )  AS totaltime 
FROM course c;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=634025bd9b889450c5f6f7d32b72d35d) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @aatj . . . I got confused on the data structure.  I see what you want now and adjusted the query (and added a fiddle to see that it works).